# Join two tables where the other table has no equivalent value in the other table using MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

I want to join two tables where some rows does not have a value in the other table.

This is the first table:

```
ID      TDNO    lotNO   area    VALUE      DATE    MEMO    
------  ------  ------  ------  ---------  ------  --------
100     1       111     100     100.00     2015    ASDASD  
101     2       222     100     100.00     2015    SDFSDF  
102     3       333     200     100.00     2015    TEST    
103     4       444     200     200.00     2015    FOO     
104     5       555     330     200.00     2015    BAR     
105     100     100     100     11,000.00  2016    100
```

This is the second table:

```
tdno    hiid    sequence_no  
------  ------  -------------
100     qwerty              0
A) 1    qwerty              1
2       qwerty              2
3       qwerty              3
4       qwerty              4
5       qwerty              5
```

What I want is that I want to join the two tables but as you can see there is a row that has no value in the other table. How to join this?

This is my query so far:

```
SELECT 
  ht.ID,
  ht.TDNO,
  ht.lotNO,
  ht.area,
  FORMAT(ht.assess_value, 2) AS 'VALUE',
  ht.EFF AS 'DATE',
  ht.memoranda AS 'MEMO',
  ts.hiid,
  ts.sequence_no 
FROM
  history_table ht 
  RIGHT JOIN td_sequence ts 
    ON ts.`tdno` = ht.`TDNO` 
WHERE hiid = 'qwerty' 
  AND sequence_no >= '0'
  ORDER BY sequence_no ASC
```

And the result is like this:

```
ID      TDNO    lotNO   area    VALUE      DATE    MEMO    hiid    sequence_no  
------  ------  ------  ------  ---------  ------  ------  ------  -------------
105     100     100     100     11,000.00  100     100     qwerty              0
(NULL)  (NULL)  (NULL)  (NULL)  (NULL)     (NULL)  (NULL)  qwerty              1
101     2       222     100     100.00     2015    SDFSDF  qwerty              2
102     3       333     200     100.00     2015    TEST    qwerty              3
103     4       444     200     200.00     2015    FOO     qwerty              4
104     5       555     330     200.00     2015    BAR     qwerty              5
```

What I want is like this:

```
ID      TDNO    lotNO   area    VALUE      DATE    MEMO    hiid    sequence_no  
------  ------  ------  ------  ---------  ------  ------  ------  -------------
105     100     100     100     11,000.00  100     100     qwerty              0
100     A) 1    111     100     100.00     2015    ASDASD  qwerty              1
101     2       222     100     100.00     2015    SDFSDF  qwerty              2
102     3       333     200     100.00     2015    TEST    qwerty              3
103     4       444     200     200.00     2015    FOO     qwerty              4
104     5       555     330     200.00     2015    BAR     qwerty              5
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: Explain, why the record with `tdno='A) 1'` was joined with the record with `TDNO='1'`. Even better to formulate a criterion which allows to find those "not equal, but matched" record pairs... then convert it to the statement and use it in JOIN condition.

Comment: the `tdno = A) 1` was entered by the user and i want to connect it to `TDNO=1` which is already in the database

Comment: You say what, and don't say why. Why with `TDNO=1` and not with `TDNO=11`, for example... In practice - autocorrection of user's misprintings gives poor quality results needed in manual checking.

Answer (score 0):

For example, it can look like

```
FROM table1
JOIN table2 ON table1.TDNO = SUBSTRING_INDEX(table2.tdno, ' ', -1)
```